# Bypass shift with pop up password box

Tags: ms-access, vba, shift

I am trying to create an access database that is shut off from the users even the bypass shift option. I have done a code that does this but what I want to add is a pop up box when the shift key is pressed that allows a user to enter a password and the bypass shift option will work again. Does anybody know if this is possible?

Thanks!

```
Function ap_DisableShift()

On Error GoTo errDisableShift

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim prop As DAO.Property
Const conPropNotFound = 3270

Set db = CurrentDb()

db.Properties("AllowByPassKey") = False

Exit Function

errDisableShift:

If Err = conPropNotFound Then
Set prop = db.CreateProperty("AllowByPassKey", _
dbBoolean, False)
db.Properties.Append prop
Resume Next
Else
MsgBox "Function 'ap_DisableShift' did not complete successfully."
Exit Function
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to catch the startup event while shift is disabled. What I always do is to add a hidden password text box on the startup form. The password text box can be activated by a 'hidden button'. The effect only applies to the next startup event (and on), so it is not as direct as you'd like it, but it is reliable.

1. Add a rectangle to the startup form that will act as a mouse catcher. Make sure that `Back Style` is set to `Normal`, but with the same color as the form's `BackColor`so it is invisible.
2. Add a hidden text box to startup form. Set `Input Mask` as `Password`
3. Add a Double_Click event to the rectangle, that will unhide the password text box
4. Add an `AfterUpdate` event to the password text box, that will enable the shift key (`AllowBypassKey`) if the password is correct. You can enter the access interface at the next startup.

To use the AllowBypassKey:

```
Public Sub CreateLockProperty()

    CurrentDb.Properties.Append CurrentDb.CreateProperty("AllowBypassKey", dbBoolean, True)

End Sub

Public Sub SetToolLock(bLocked As Boolean)

    CurrentDb.Properties("AllowBypassKey") = Not bLocked

End Sub

Public Function ToolLocked() As Boolean

    ToolLocked = Not CurrentDb.Properties("AllowBypassKey")

End Function
```

First you have to create the property by running the first procedure. After that you can use the other two.

Comment: I have added the code I have to bypass the shift how do I add the password part to this code?

Comment: Ok well... I thought the code about worked but it does not, do you have a code to disable the shift button?

Comment: You'd best search for `AllowBypassKey`. there are numerous post about it. If it works then we can look at the password part of your query.

Comment: I keep searching and trying all types of codes and none work... is it because I have my database as an .accdb?

Comment: I added information about `AllowBypassKey` the my answer

Comment: Ok so I should add all this to a new module and then just set the allowbypasskey option to true if the password is correct behind the text box?

Comment: Ahh ok I finally have a code that shuts off the shift but now I need to figure out the code to add to the password text box